# How to configure login screen in Xubuntu 18.04 - Slick Greeter

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, login, lightdm, unity-greeter

I have installed Xubuntu 18.04.

The login screen shows lightdm gtk greeter like login.
I didn't like this type of view so I installed slick greeter through terminal and removed gtk greeter through command.

Now login shows slick greeter but background is black with white dots.

How to change this background or how I can easily configure login scree settings like i configure desktop settings .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to install the package `lightdm-settings`

```
sudo apt install lightdm-settings
```

This is the graphical utility to configure slick-greeter

It will appear in your menu once installed as "Login window"

[image]

Comment: Yes it works .and its easy to operate .thank u